# Problems to login with Passport 11 (Laravel 10) Page Not Found

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

Upgrading from Laravel 9 to 10. I can register user, change users password, show list of competitions but can't login. This is the system working in Laravel 9:
http://shoot.mywire.org
Looking at Passport upgrade, all in the upgrade guide contains
a lot of controllers and files that I have never seen. In this project
there are just a few parts responsible for user auth, as these:

```
app/Http/Controllers/Api/AuthenticateController.php
app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php
routes/api.php
```

These are responsible for user authorize.

In Laravel 9 the AuthServiceProvider.php contains this:

```
    public function boot(): void
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
        Passport::routes(null, ['prefix' => 'api/'.'v'.env('API_VERSION').'/oauth']);

    }
```

If I use that in Laravel 10 I'm getting 'Call to undefined method Laravel\Passport\Passport::routes()'.

If I comment out the line I'm getting "Page not found" or in the browser:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v4.1.9/oauth/token

I wonder where to start looking for the solution.

Regards, Ralph in Sweden